# What should I use instead of "align" attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, xhtml

I'm studying asp.net mvc 3 (using Razor).
One of my *.cshtml views has the following code:

```
<p align="center">
    <input class="actionButtons" type="submit" value="Complete order" />
</p>
```

The VS2010 C# compiler shows me a "*XHTML1.0 Transitional*" check message (not an error, not a warning), saying that `align` attribute is supposed to be deprecated, and a new construction is recommended.

What is that construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means `"text-align:center"`. Or other way is `style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"`

Comment: I thought `text-align` won't work for an `actionButton`..but it works! and no messages from the compiler...after some edits it stopped abusing `align` as well though...mmm..strange

Comment: In the end it doesn't like `align` indeed...but it needs some time to show that message...`<p style="text-align:center">...</p>` I' ll stop on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch using CSS rules (if you want to position text in the center inside of the p)

```
<p style="text-align: center">
```

But if you want to position p element itself in the center, its need to be width constrained and margins set to auto:

```
<p style="width: 50%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
```

More on horizontal aligning [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but Pavel Bakshy was the first to give me this piece of advice

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the answer to your question is that the "new" way of aligning things in CSS, whether it be text or other elements, is using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).

You should take a look at this article: [Align content with CSS](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/p/css-align.htm%5d), which explains different techniques for aligning content with CSS and provides links to detailed explanations too.

Comment: I'll think in that way in future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `HTML4` and above `align` attribute of `p` tag has been deprectaed. You should use

```
<p style="text-align:center">
    <input class="actionButtons" type="submit" value="Complete order" />
</p>
```

Some other tags and attributes have been deprecated. You can read about them [here](http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/deprecated.html)